# PhpStorm not publishing to Docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

I have a fresh install of PhpStorm 2020.1, Docker Desktop 2.3.0.3 (45519) on Windows 10 (1909).

I am trying to follow the instructions on how to start up a dev environment.

I have followed the instructions that come with PhpStorm and it all seems to startup, but I can not open the example page `HelloWorld.php`

Below is my setup, can someone offer some advice on what I am missing.

[image: PhpStorm Setup]

[image: Docker Setup]

The docker-compose.yml that is shown above is from "PHPStorm Workshop Project", it is not something that I have created.
[PHPStorm Workshop Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/workshop-materials.html#running-docker)

```
version: '2'
services:
  debug:
    image: phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./workshop/07_Debugging:/var/www/html
    environment:
      #For Windows and macOS, replace the line below with `host.docker.internal`, which will automatically resolve to the internal address of the host Docker is running on.
      #For Linux, replace the line below with your hostname, which you can obtain by executing `hostname` in Terminal.
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal

      #For macOS, if you use a local Homebrew php-fpm installation, port `9000` (which is the default debugging port) may become occupied. PhpStorm will remain silent on starting listening for incoming connections. If this is the case, in the Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug, set the Debug port to 9001, and use the following configuration line instead.

      #XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal, remote_port=9001

  sftp:
    image: phpstorm/sftp-server
    ports:
      - "2022:22"
    volumes:
      #   Uncomment for Windows
       - C:/temp:/home/jetbrains/upload
        #   Uncomment for macOS/Linux
      # - /tmp:/home/jetbrains/upload
    command: jetbrains:jetbrains:1001
  mysql:
    image: phpstorm/mysql
    ports:
      - "33056:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

=====================

As LazyOne pointed out, I miss read the port number hosted page, I should have tried 8081.
This just shows a 404 though.

[image: 404Page]

Looking into the docker images I can see...

Image: phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug

Log:

```
[Mon Jun 29 09:38:13.391958 2020] [php7:error] [pid 17] [client 172.19.0.1:38860] script '/var/www/html/HelloWorld.php' not found or unable to stat

172.19.0.1 - - [29/Jun/2020:09:38:13 +0000] "GET /HelloWorld.php HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Image: phpstorm/mysql

Log:

```
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.20-1.1.16

[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.20-1.1.16

2020-06-29T09:39:55.936014Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1

2020-06-29T09:39:55.966003Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2020-06-29T09:39:56.460720Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(16, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.473039Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(17, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.496812Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(18, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.518401Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(19, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.532661Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(20, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.551602Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(21, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.565370Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(22, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.581883Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(23, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.597827Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(24, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.615128Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(25, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-29T09:39:56.654877Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.

2020-06-29T09:39:56.887730Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060

2020-06-29T09:39:56.986555Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.

2020-06-29T09:39:57.004613Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Input/output error

2020-06-29T09:39:57.005010Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?

2020-06-29T09:39:57.005476Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2020-06-29T09:39:58.254400Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20) MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I'm not aware of anything else running on port 22.

Comment: 1) I see nothing about "not publishing" here (like errors or warnings)... 2) As per your first screenshot, the website should be running on port 8081 yet you are opening `localhost` only. Please try the expected `localhost:8081` instead.

Comment: Please share more details. Usually, you should not add code in images

Comment: I have not used that totorial/image from JetBrains so cannot say how it works there exactly, but looking that the docker-compose.yml (the `- ./workshop/07_Debugging:/var/www/html` line) and the path where your HelloWorld.php is located (the project root) and where Docker tries to locate it (`/var/www/html/HelloWorld.php`) ... try moving that file into `/workshop/07_Debugging` folder.

Comment: LazyOne, you legend! Please post your comment as an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to your screenshots and `docker-compose.yml` file content:

1. You should use `localhost:8081` instead of just `localhost` in your browser.
2. You should move your HelloWorld.php file into `/workshop/07_Debugging` folder as this is the folder that is getting mapped/accessible inside the container. Your project root folder where HelloWorld.php is currently located is outside of that "accessible/mapped" path.